# Direct CGI call or PHP exec/system?

Tags: php, cgi, system, exec

I have the option to execute a program directly via CGI or use PHP exec/system instead. What is the difference? Also can you say which one is more secure?

Comment: If you say "directly via CGI" then that necessitates an exec() call. Hencwhy there wouldn't be much of a difference, likely not security-wise either. (But that's hard to tell since you didn't give enough context.)

Comment: Thanks Mario, I have a CGI script which takes a userName variable and then starts extracting data from another website to put it into a MySQL DB. Now I was thinking what the best way to call this script would be. Is there a noticable difference performance-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a script via CGI is not much different from executing it directly. Just use the PHP-CGI binary and do:

```
exec("SCRIPT_FILENAME=cgi.php QUERY_STRING=userName=user123 php-cgi");
// use escapeshellarg() for variable parameters!
```

Most of the CGI environment variables are already in the current PHP environment, so you only need to override a few. `QUERY_STRING` corresponds to the `$_GET[]` variables for example.

Performance-wise there is little difference. It's oftentimes faster than if you were to invoke another subrequest `file_get_contents("http://localhost/cgi.php?user=123")` over the webserver however.